# React/TypeScript .map over array not rendering dropdown option

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the below code I am trying to populate the option tags of my drop down from the response from my API call. Not sure why its not showing as when I check the debugger in the browser it is definitely hitting the endpoint, all I get is an empty drop down.

My code for the component:

```
interface ExpensesState {
  date: Date;
  isLoading: Boolean;
  expenses: ICategory[];
  categories: ICategory[];
}

const Expenses: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<ExpensesState>({
    date: new Date(),
    isLoading: true,
    expenses: new Array<ICategory>(),
    categories: new Array<ICategory>(),
  });

  const getCategories = () => {
    const service = new CategoryService();
    service
      .getAll()
      .then((response) => {
        setState({ ...state, categories: response });
        setState({ ...state, isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => getCategories(), []);

  const handleChange = () => {};
  const title = <h3>Add Expense</h3>;

    return (
    <>
      <div>
        <AppNav />
        <Container>
          {title}
          <Form>
            <FormGroup>
              <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="title"
                id="title"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <label htmlFor="Category">Category</label>
              <select >
                {!state.isLoading
                  ? state.categories.map(({id, name}) => (
                      <option key={id.toString()} value={name}>{name}</option>
                    ))
                  : <option>Loading...</option>}
              </select>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="category"
                id="category"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        </Container>
      </div>
        </>
    )}
```

This is my CategoryService where I make the call to the API.

```
class CategoryService {
  async getAll(): Promise<ICategory[]> {
    const response = await fetch(`/category`, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    return response.ok ? response.json() : null;
  }
}

export default CategoryService;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The double `setState` inside `getCategories` suspicious, what happens if you merge them? Something like `setState({ ...state, categories: response, isLoading: false })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the react cli app, you should get a warning in the browser console telling you that `useEffect` has a missing dependency on `getCategories`.

Though simply adding it would result in an infinite loop (`getCategories` is redefined on every render, but triggers a re-render [because of `setState`]);

Also, you're calling `setState` twice re-using the *outer* state. But because of it's *asynchronous* nature, the second call *overwrites* the changes from the first. So even so, the state is no longer *loading* the responses are lost.

---

A solution that worked for me, was to change the hook to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // inlined
  const getCategories = () => {
    const service = new CategoryService();

    service
      .getAll()
      .then((response) => {
        // use the function version of `setState` to be independent of the outer
        // state value (also, no need to call it twice, just update both values).
        setState(prev => ({...prev, categories: response, isLoading: false}));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  // call
  getCategories()
}, []); // no dependencies => only called once
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-volhard-muj4k?file=/src/Expenses.tsx

---

On a side note, `CategoryService.getAll` does not adhere to it's contract. It should always return a `Promise<ICategory[]>` but might sometimes return `Promise<null>`.

Comment: Hi Yoshi. Thanks for the code snippet and the explanation. Working on my end here.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to verify if the mapping is properly done:

- `state.isLoading` is *false* after the `useEffect(() => getCategories(), []);` call (try to remove the select condition first)
- `ICategory` composed of a number *id* and a string *name*
- `service.getAll()` response is indeed returning an array of *ICategories*
- check each element of the array inside the `map()` without destructuring the `ICategory`:

  ```
  state.categories.map(cat => { // not destructuring
    console.log('mapped category:', cat);
    return <option key={cat.id.toString()} value={cat.name}>{cat.name}</option>;
  })
  ```